# Bootstrap Dropdown Menu link issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have created a dropdown menu which can be seen in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m0gb0y74/4RBJm/)

```
<div id="navbarContainer" class="container-fluid">
            <nav class="navbar">
                <div class="navbar-inner">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li class="dropdown" data-toggle="tab">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" href="#">Adult
                                <i class="caret"></i>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="/">AL4 Participant Record</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown" data-toggle="tab">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#"  href="#">Youth
                                <i class="caret"></i>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="/Home/Youth">YS2</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li data-toggle="tab"><a class="course" href="/Course">Courses</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
```

When I click YS2 under the Youth menu, I want to navigate to to the actual url - how do i make this happen?

Comment: Please post rendered HTML, not whatever that is. I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: Ah, you just did. :-) Still, I don't understand the question. What does "actual URL" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the data-toggle="tab" from the outer li.

Your html should look like this for that menu when you are done.

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#"  href="#">Youth
       <i class="caret"></i>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="/Home/Youth">YS2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```